# Apply elisp function to any file

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to apply an elisp function to a specific file, which is not in an open buffer?

Eg `(my/apply delete-duplicate-lines "~/tmp")`

Comment: Is your file already in an open buffer, or do you need to open it first?  And, do you want to save the file -- if so, with a prompt or without a prompt to overwrite?

Comment: @lawlist apply to a file, not to a buffer, therefore "save file" (without a prompt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this to the marked files of Dired, if you use library [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([**`dired+.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)).

- **`@`** in Dired prompts you for a function (a function name or a lambda expression), and it then applies the function to the marked files.

  By default, it applies the function to each marked file *name*. The function can do whatever you like, but it needs to accept a file name as argument.  (The function need not visit the file.)

  With a plain prefix arg (`C-u`), each marked file is *visited* and the function is invoked (with no arguments) in the visiting buffer.
- **`M-+ @`** in Dired does the same thing, but it acts on all marked files and all files marked in any marked subdirectories, defined *recursively*.  (`M-+` is a prefix key for operations on the marked files, defined recursively over subdirectories.)

  The files acted on are those that are marked in the current Dired
  buffer, or all files in the directory if none are marked.  Marked
  subdirectories are handled recursively in the same way.

  Just as for `@`, a plain prefix arg (`C-u`) means *visit* each file and invoke the function with no arguments.

  Any other prefix arg behaves according to the `ARG` argument of the **Dired+** version of `dired-get-marked-files`.  In particular, `C-u C-u` operates on ***all*** files in the Dired buffer - it ignores markings.
  More precisely:

  - If `ARG` is an *integer*, act on the next `ARG` files (previous -`ARG`, if < 0).
  - If `ARG` is a cons with element 16, 64, or 256, corresponding to
    **`C-u C-u`**, **`C-u C-u C-u`**, or **`C-u C-u C-u C-u`**, then act on **all** files in the Dired buffer, where:

    - 16 includes **no** directories (including `.` and `..`)
    - 64 includes directories **except** `.` and `..`
    - 256 includes **all** directories (including `.` and `..`)
  - If `ARG` is otherwise non-`nil`, act on the current file only.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to do

```
(with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "~/tmp")
  (delete-duplicate-lines (point-min) (point-max))
  (save-buffer))
```

If you want more information on how to programmatically operate on buffer contents read this [section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffers.html#Buffers)

Comment: You can just open the file with (find-file-no-select "~/tmp") and use that as the first argument to with-current-buffer

Comment: `noselect`  -- one word -- :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want also to cleanup the buffer etc, you could use

```
(let ((file "~/tmp"))
  (with-temp-file file
    (insert-file-contents file)
    (delete-duplicate-lines (point-min) (point-max))))
```